# Calling and json file and displaying it on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to display images from my json file on a html page and organise them into rows of 3 or 4. Below is an example of the layout I want my page but this is hard coded,I have included images because I have having difficulty pasting the code (I can put this on fiddler) don't mind some of the word under the pictures some p tags needed taken out:

HTML:

```
<div id="container"> 
<div class="row"> 
<div class="product-container"> </div> 
<div class="col-sm-4"> 
<img src="Image/iphone5.jpg" alt="StrappyMeshInsertDress" style="width:200px;height:250px"> 
<p><span> class="bold">Iphone5s</span><br /> 
</div>
```

Here is a snip from my json file:

[json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeLVA.jpg)

I am using this script to call the data although it has not been calling the json file:

[the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWCHp.jpg)

I have positioned the images when hard coding like this:

I have been at this for over a day and cannot get it to work, If anyone has any ideas on how to get this to work I would be very grateful.

Kind regards!

Comment: Please include the code (not a picture of the code) and data (ditto) in the question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lmac1/exm0ha8t/

Comment: here is the code on fiddler I put the json file into the script to give an example but I will be calling the json from an external file - (part of the assignment). There may be some faults in my script and I also want to know how to position them like the way I have done using:

Comment: <div id="container">
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="product-container">
                
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="Image/iphone5.jpg" alt="StrappyMeshInsertDress" style="width:200px;height:250px">
                    <p><span> class="bold">Iphone5s</span><br />
                </div>

Comment: There is no need to include the style-sheet and js libraries and also html Doctype, body and head tag in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you are appending JSON data dynamically so please remove the HTML content, or only make a parent container who will hold all this Output data.Make a JSON file with the name 'iproducts.json' on the same path.

```
$.getJSON('iproducts.json',function(products){
        var output=" <table border='1'><thead><th>Product_id</th><th>Info</th><th>Imgpath</th><th>Price</th><tbody>";
$.each(products.appleitems,function(index,value){
 output+="<tr><td>"  + value.Product_id + "</td><td></td></td><td>" + value.Information+"</td><td>"+"<img src ='images/" + value.Imgpath + ".jpg' alt='applepro' id='appleinf'" + value.Price +"</td><td>"
});

output+="</tbody></table>";
console.log("output =" + output);
```